# I'm making a game with Pygame, my player is going of the corners though i specified the boundaries

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I started leaning Pygame recently and tried to make a game and in the middle of that I got a problem. I made a player which will not move out of the screen and it is good till the sides but, when it reaches the corners its going off the screen. if u don't get my question, copy my code and run it in your computer then move the player with arrow keys then move to wards the end of the screen and corners, you will get it now.

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')

# Title and Icon
title = pygame.display.set_caption('space')
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# player
playerIMG = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0
playerY_change = 0

# enemy
enemyIMG = pygame.image.load('enemy.png')
enemyX = random.randint(0, 768)
enemyY = random.randint(50, 150)
enemyX_change = 1
enemyY_change = 0

# bullet
bulletIMG = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 1
bullet_state = "ready"


def player(X, Y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG, (X, Y))


def enemy(X, Y):
    screen.blit(enemyIMG, (X, Y))


def fire_bullet(X, Y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletIMG, (X+10, Y+10))


# Game loop
running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        # key strokes
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = +1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY_change = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_change = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state is "ready":
                    bulletX = playerX
                    bulletY = playerY
                    fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -0.3
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.3
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP :
                playerY_change = -0.3
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN :
                playerY_change = +0.3

    player(playerX, playerY)
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)

    # player boundaries
    playerX += playerX_change
    playerY += playerY_change

    if playerX < 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736
    elif playerY <= 0:
        playerY = 0
    elif playerY > 480:
        playerY = 480

    # enemy movement
    enemyX += enemyX_change
    if enemyX <= 0:
        enemyX_change = 1
    elif enemyX >= 736:
        enemyX_change = -1

    # bullet movement
    if bulletY <= 0:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"
    if bullet_state is 'fire':
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change



    print(playerX, playerY)[enter image description here][1]
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the x and y direction separately. If the player exceeds the limits in the x direction, the y direction is not evaluated because you are using an `if`-`elif` sequence:

```py
running = True
while running:
    # [...]
 
    if playerX < 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736

    # elif playerY <= 0:    <---  DELETE

    if playerY <= 0:      # <---  ADD
        playerY = 0
    elif playerY > 480:
        playerY = 480
```